# CKEDITOR : How do you get an instance of the Editor in typescript with CKEDITOR4

Tags: angular, typescript, ckeditor, editor, instance

How does one get a handle on the CKEDITOR 4 plugin in Typescript (app is Angular 9)?

I need to set the config via typescript (autogrow) and try to do an INSERT HTML function.

I have imported the module (see below) ... but not much in the properties.

import { CKEditor4 } from 'ckeditor4-angular/ckeditor';

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

1. Add #editor in html `<ckeditor #editor formControlName="resumen" data="<p>Hello, world!</p>"></ckeditor>`
2. in component add this `@ViewChild('editor') editor;`
3. And now you can access with:

   ```
    console.log(this.editor);
   ```

Comment: Thanks Elyas, this is what I expected.